# First Node of the Intersection between 2 Singly Linked Lists - Time & Space Complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the time & space complexity of this method I wrote which returns the first node of the intersection between two singly linked lists (and if none found just null)?

```
public Node getFirstNodeWhichIntersects(Node node1, Node node2) {
    Node currentPtr1 = node1;
    Node currentPtr2 = node2;   
    Node firstNode = null;
      
    while (currentPtr1 != null) {
       currentPtr2 = node2;
       while (currentPtr2 != null) {
          if (currentPtr1 == currentPtr2) {
              return currentPtr1;
          }     
          currentPtr2 = currentPtr2.next;
       }
       currentPtr1 = currentPtr1.next;
    }
    return firstNode;
}
```

Comment: *"which returns the intersection of the first node..."*: I suppose you mean *"which returns the first node of the intersection..."*.

Comment: BTW, if linked lists don't cycle, a simple algorithm will determine whether two lists have a common tail while examining every node once, and find the start of the tail accessing each node at most once more.

Comment: @supercat - Are you suggesting my solution is sub-optimal or is missing an edge case? If so, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case the tail node of both lists is the first node that is shared. This algorithm will only find it by testing **all** possible pairs of nodes (one from the first list, one from the other).

So that gives this algorithm a worst time complexity of O(), where  and  are the number of nodes in the first and second linked list. Note that there are algorithms for this problem with a time complexity of O(+).

The space complexity is trivial: there are a constant number of variables, each with a constant memory footprint, so the space complexity is O(1).